# Model issues with AR.js and A-frame

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, gltf, ar.js

So I am working on a tutorial with A-frame and AR.js, and I've just copied in the code and subbed in my own model but the model will not load into the scene, I've played around with the scale and lighting of the model in Blender to try different sizes and configurations but the model will just not load in. I've been having a hard time figuring out how to format the model because I am certain the problem is with my model because the code works fine.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot/modify models so that they will actually load in?

Here's the code with my not-working model for reference, Thanks in advance!

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs>

<a-gltf-model src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/3164255/AR_TEST/master/ROCK_TEST_2.gltf" scale="1 1 1"></a->

    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your glTF file calls for a `.bin` file that's not present in the same folder.  Specifically, on [line 112](https://github.com/3164255/AR_TEST/blob/f837363e4063c0aeaa1cbeecb1c3f05c55d9f3d8/ROCK_TEST_2.gltf#L112), it asks for a file named `buffer_ROCK_TEST_2.bin`, but this file isn't present.

glTF files typically come in two forms.  The `*.gltf` form is a plain-text JSON formatted file that often refers to external files such as `.bin`, `.jpg`, and `.png` files.  The mesh data is all stored in the bin file, and the model cannot render without it.

The other form of glTF is stored in a `.glb` file.  This is a binary bundle that includes the JSON and images and mesh data all in a single file.